# Exporting JAVA_HOME has no effect when execute in *.sh on macOS BigSur

Tags: java, macos, sh

I have a script j16.sh with content:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 16.0.1`
echo Java 16
```

When I run the script on the terminal (zsh) using

```
./j16.sh
```

it prints "Java 16", but when I call "java --version", the version has not changed to 16.

However, when I execute the "export" line (copied from the script" directly on the terminal), the Java version gets switched, as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Apparently, executed in the script, the line has no effect - but the echo-line has?

Comment: You need to `source` the script, not execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Source](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)

`source j16.sh`

This will run the commands of the script rather than launching a new shell, and that will result in setting the environment .